# WSO2 User Management API Sample and Active Directory

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have the sample code working perfectly if I use the default user store.

Using AD as the user store, I can add users with the WSO2 Management Console, but the some API calls fail.

The API does create the role, and it looks like it partially creates the user, but then it craps out.

Here is the relevant part of the server log:

```
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,306] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  wso2_admin user has permitted role :  admin
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,307]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'WSO2_Admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2015-08-27 20:36:44,307+0000]
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,458] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Authorization cache miss for username : wso2_admin resource /permission/admin/configure/security action : ui.execute
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,459] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Allowed roles for the ResourceID: /permission/admin/configure/security Action: ui.execute
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,459] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  role: admin
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,459] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Roles which have permission for resource : /permission/admin/configure/security action : ui.execute
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,459] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Role :  admin
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,459] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  wso2_admin user has permitted role :  admin
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,460] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for role: localhost
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,460] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using search filter: (&(objectcategory=group)(cn=localhost))
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,680] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching in OU=IAM,DC=local
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,686] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Is role: localhost exist: false
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,753] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for role: localhost
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,754] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using search filter: (&(objectcategory=group)(cn=localhost))
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,982] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching in OU=IAM,DC=local
[2015-08-27 20:36:44,983] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Is role: localhost exist: false
[2015-08-27 20:36:45,326] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user WSO2_Testuser_7
[2015-08-27 20:36:45,552] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(cn=WSO2_Testuser_7)) in SearchBase:
[2015-08-27 20:36:45,553] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for WSO2_Testuser_7 is null
[2015-08-27 20:36:45,554] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: WSO2_Testuser_7 exist: false
[2015-08-27 20:36:45,623] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user WSO2_Testuser_7
[2015-08-27 20:36:45,832] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(cn=WSO2_Testuser_7)) in SearchBase:
[2015-08-27 20:36:45,833] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for WSO2_Testuser_7 is null
[2015-08-27 20:36:45,834] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: WSO2_Testuser_7 exist: false
[2015-08-27 20:36:45,834] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for role: localhost
[2015-08-27 20:36:45,834] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using search filter: (&(objectcategory=group)(cn=localhost))
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,035] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching in OU=IAM,DC=local
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,037] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Is role: localhost exist: true
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,037] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for role: loginOnly
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,037] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using search filter: (&(objectcategory=group)(cn=loginOnly))
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,254] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching in OU=IAM,DC=local
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,256] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Is role: loginOnly exist: true
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,257] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user WSO2_Testuser_7
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,484] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(cn=WSO2_Testuser_7)) in SearchBase:
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,486] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for WSO2_Testuser_7 is null
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,486] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: WSO2_Testuser_7 exist: false
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,699] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} -  AttributeName: sn AttributeValue: Powell
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,699] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} -  AttributeName: mail AttributeValue: andy.powell@outlook.com
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,699] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} -  AttributeName: givenName AttributeValue: Andrew
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,955] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(cn=WSO2_Testuser_7)) in SearchBase:
[2015-08-27 20:36:46,957] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for WSO2_Testuser_7 is CN=WSO2_Testuser_7,OU=IAM,DC=local
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,176] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for role: localhost
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,176] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using search filter: (&(objectcategory=group)(cn=localhost))
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,376] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching in OU=IAM,DC=local
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,378] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Is role: localhost exist: true
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,379] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Modifying role: CN=localhost with type: 1 user: CN=WSO2_Testuser_7,OU=IAM,DC=local in search base: OU=IAM,DC=local
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,642] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: CN=WSO2_Testuser_7,OU=IAM,DC=local was successfully modified in LDAP group: CN=localhost
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,643] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for role: loginOnly
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,643] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using search filter: (&(objectcategory=group)(cn=loginOnly))
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,925] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching in OU=IAM,DC=local
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,927] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Is role: loginOnly exist: true
[2015-08-27 20:36:47,929] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Modifying role: CN=loginOnly with type: 1 user: CN=WSO2_Testuser_7,OU=IAM,DC=local in search base: OU=IAM,DC=local
[2015-08-27 20:36:48,145] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: CN=WSO2_Testuser_7,OU=IAM,DC=local was successfully modified in LDAP group: CN=loginOnly


NOTE: WSO2_Testuser_7 was not actually created in AD.

Here is the Eclipse Console message:

org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while enabling the user account. Please check password policy at DC
    at org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.WSUserStoreManager.handleException(WSUserStoreManager.java:485)
    at org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.WSUserStoreManager.addUser(WSUserStoreManager.java:139)
    at org.wso2.identity.um.sample.IdentityServerClient.main(IdentityServerClient.java:99)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while enabling the user account. Please check password policy at DC
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation$RobustOutOnlyOperationClient.handleResponse(RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation.java:91)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.addUser(RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.java:2276)
    at org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.WSUserStoreManager.addUser(WSUserStoreManager.java:136)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: `String[] userRoles = storeManager.getRoleListOfUser(newUser)` returns 1 string: "Internal/everyone" for the user, but they don't appear in AD.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try checking over the user-mgt.xml password parameter regex.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+an+Active+Directory+User+Store

As a thought (may not be wrong) I would have thought these log messages should be coming from the `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager`, class not `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager`. Your user-mgt.xml is set up to use that class, yes?

Comment: This was on the track to how to fix it.  The regex didn't match what was required by the underlying AD, so WSO2 let me try to create users with passwords that AD found too weak, which resulted in a cryptic error message.

Also, if the admin username in your user-mgt.xml has any CAPITAL LETTERS in it, hilarity ensues.